# Spark unit test compilation error when using Spark testing base

Tags: scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

I am getting the following error

```
Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference. A signature in DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.class refers to term hive
in package org.apache.spark.sql which is not available.
It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling  
DataFrameSuiteBaseLike.class
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Spark Hive library to your dependencies.
For instance in SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.1"
```

This is mentioned in the project at
https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/issues/93